# How could I get the API response with Brython?

Tags: python, api, browser, local-storage, brython

I'm trying to make a little function which get responses from Spotify's API through Brython (Browser Python) for a bigger project.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work when I try to get `localStorage['apiResponse']` because it seems like Python doesn't wait for `on_complete` to complete and proceed with the main function without worrying that localStorage is empty for now (which leads me getting an empty string instead of the API response.

I tried lots of things like `set_timeout()` or `aio.sleep` (in an async'ed function) but both of them don't wait for the end of the execution and proceed with the rest of the program.

Also `while` loops freezes the browser... (as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593343/while-loop-makes-the-browser-freeze-with-brython))

```
from browser import ajax #to make requests
from browser.local_storage import storage as localStorage #to access HTML5 Local Storage

import json #to convert a json-like string into a Python Dict

#Request to the API
def on_complete(req):
    if req.status==200 or req.status==0:
        localStorage['apiResponse'] = req.text
    else:
        print("An error occured while asking Spotify for data")

def apiRequest(requestUrl, requestMethod):
    req = ajax.ajax()
    req.bind('complete', on_complete)
    req.open(requestMethod, requestUrl, True)
    req.set_header('Authorization', localStorage['header'])
    req.send()
```

I have a header with my token in `localStorage['header']` for those who are wondering.

The problem doesn't come from the request to the API because I can see the request working in my 'Network' tab of my Chrome DevTools.

Python 3 and Brython 3.8.7

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely that Brython isn't waiting to receive the input from the API before concluding its execution.

I myself recently just began working with Brython, but it appears with synchronous requests, you need to find a way to delay program execution while awaiting the server response. If not, execution is concluded before the API response is ever received.

Something that has worked for me is toggling the "blocking" boolean in the Ajax request.

Trying `req.open(requestMethod, requestUrl, False)` should toggle the "blocking" status of your request- This "blocks" program execution, making sure the response from the server has been received before actually executing `on_complete()` and the rest of the program after that.

Hopefully this helps. It fixed my issue.

PS: An alternative would be working with asynchronous Ajax functions. Information on that is available here: [Brython AIO Docs](https://brython.info/static_doc/en/aio.html)